# AWS CLI not reading config file

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I have my CLI setup so that `[default]` is for my account at work and `[jacoblambert]` is my personal account. When I try to access `S3` using the following command:

```
aws --profile jacoblambert s3 ls
```

I am met with the following error:

```
A client error (InvalidRequest) occurred when calling the GetBucketLocation operation: 
You are attempting to operate on a bucket in a region that requires Signature Version 4.  
You can fix this issue by explicitly providing the correct region location using the --region argument, 
    the AWS_DEFAULT_REGION environment variable, 
    or the region variable in the AWS CLI configuration file.
```

But the thing is, the `region` variable is set in the AWS CLI congifuration file (I pulled out the keys):

```
~ $ aws configure list --profile jacoblambert
   Name                    Value             Type    Location
   ----                    -----             ----    --------
profile             jacoblambert           manual    --profile
 region                us-east-2      config-file    ~/.aws/config
```

If I specify `--region us-east-2` in the `aws s3` command, I am still met with the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you found the root cause because of `out of date`?

The problem you reported is about [Amazon S3 Signature Version 4 Authentication Specific Policy Keys](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/bucket-policy-s3-sigv4-conditions.html)

You should be fine to fix with the command

```
aws configure set profile.jacoblambert.s3.signature_version s3v4
```

or add below lines to that profile `[jacoblambert]` in ~/.aws/config

```
s3 =
    signature_version = s3v4
```

Refer:

[Specifying Signature Version in Request Authentication](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingAWSSDK.html#specify-signature-version)

Comment: My AWS-CLI version was `aws-cli/1.10.34`. After upgrading to `aws-cli/1.11.82` I no longer had the issue. For me, the issue seems to be an outdated CLI installation.

Comment: ok, but I still don't agree that upgrade aws cli can fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was caused by my CLI being out of date.